# Screen sizes in DevTools do not match actual device sizes

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's DevTools, when I select a mobile device to display a web page, I notice that the screen size in DevTools does not match the device's actual screen resolution. For example, if I select a Pixel 2 XL, the width shown in DevTools is 412. But the device is actually 1440 in width. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the Pixel 2 XL has a pixel density of 3.5 so while the device resolution of the device is 1440 x 2880 px it's CSS resolution is 412 x 823 px ((1440 / 3.5) x (2880 / 3.5))

A pixel does not have an inherent size. It obtains one when it’s displayed or printed.

You can read more about the difference between device and CSS resolutions [here](https://elad.medium.com/understanding-the-difference-between-css-resolution-and-device-resolution-28acae23da0b).

You can find device and CSS resolutions for many devices [here](https://yesviz.com/).